# Showing servlet's list output in table using ajax asynchronously

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, asynchronous

I'm new to ajax and don't know how to use it for displaying my data from sevlet on page asynchronously.Moreover I must **not** to use additional libraries like jquery. So I have to "reinvent a wheel" not knowing how it wheel looks like. So I have simple servlet which sends to my request `List` of plain beans, here is it's `doGet`:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<Category> categoryList = dao.getCategoryList();

        request.setAttribute(PARAM_NAME_CATEGORY_LIST, categoryList);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext()
            .getRequestDispatcher(PRODUCT_PAGE);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

And after forwarding to my page I need to represent data in table with help of ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Loading data and displaying it in AJAX is made in several steps:

1. The page sends an AJAX request to a URL of the wabapp. It registers a JavaScript callback function that will be called when the response to the request is received.
2. The webapp generates a response to this request. The content of the response could be HTML, XML, JSON or anything else.
3. The JavaScript callback function is called.
4. The JavaScript callback function gets the data from the response, and updates the DOM tree of the page to display the received data.

Googling for "AJAX example" will lead you to plenty of tutorials explaining how to do that. If you have a more specific problem, come back.